# Остаются ли данные после завершения работы программы Python?

Tags: python, память

Есть программа на Python, которая запрашивает некоторые данные у пользователя из консоли, затем помещает их в переменные и использует. Вопрос - после завершения работы программы, эти данные каким-либо образом очищаются или нет? Просто не хотелось бы даже в оперативной памяти оставлять эти данные, ибо там API-ключ. Если эти данные остаются где-либо, то есть ли возможность очистить эти данные посредством кода в том же Python?

Comment: Я - новичок в программировании и я был бы очень рад, если бы вы приложили какую-либо ссылку на статью или любой другой информационный источник для расширения своих знаний в этой сфере (хранение переменных в памяти после завершения работы программы и т.п.)

Comment: Если вы хотите гарантированно стереть ключ из оперативной памяти, то с Python это будет проблематично, потому что он не даёт вам прямого контроля над памятью. Но вообще зачем чистить память? Операционная система в любом случае не позволит другим программам читать чужую память

Comment: Чтобы ответить на ваш вопрос надо знать как ключ попал в оперативную память, сколько там находился, куда вы его отправляли, копировали. Нужен полный жизненнный цикл ключа. Желательно в виде рабочего кода.

Comment: "(хранение переменных в памяти после завершения работы программы и т.п.)" - вот [такой же вопрос обсуждался](https://www.cyberforum.ru/cpp-beginners/thread1602375.html)